# How to use optional chaining operator with variable in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.5, typescript1.9

I have following code and I would like to pass number from value key of variable object, How can I use variable for optional chaining operator for it to solve the error Element implicitly has an `any` type?

```
    function fun(i?: number) {
        console.log(i)
    }

    const variable = { min: { value: 1, name: 'google' }, max: {value: 2, name: 'apple'} }
    const variable2 = { min: { value: 1, name: 'google' } }
    const variable3 = { max: {value: 2, name: 'apple'} }

    fun(variable?.min.value) // working => 1
    fun(variable?.max.value) // working => 2
    fun(variable2?.min.value) // working => 1
    fun(variable2?.max.value) // working => undefined
    fun(variable3?.min.value) // working => undefined
    fun(variable3?.max.value) // working => 2

    Object.keys(variable).forEach((key) => {
        fun(variable?.[key]?.value) // working but with error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ min: { value: number; name: string; }; max: { value: number; name: string; }; }'.
    })
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13254

Comment: `.[key]` looks like invalid syntax.  Given that you are getting the key by looping over the variable, the variable has to exist.  `variable[key]` should always be valid in the forEach

Comment: @Taplar it's not `.[key]` it's `?.[key]`, it's a new composite operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: `?` there isn't the safety operator?

Comment: @Taplar it's a `?.[]` operator, optional chaining + indexing.

Comment: So it is the safety operator.  Why would you use that in this specific case, when the variable *has* to exist?

Comment: @Taplar it's not me who asked the question. But nevertheless, in this very case it wouldn't change anything, see my first comment with a link to github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't actually an optional chaining problem, but a problem with how `Object.keys` works. [Typescript assumes that an object may have more keys than is known at compile time](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) so the type of `key` here is `string` and not `keyof variable`. To get around that you would have to let the TS compiler know that all the keys are known at compile time using

```
Object.keys(variable).forEach((key) => {
  fun(variable[key as keyof typeof variable].value) 
})
```

You're already treating `variable` as a non-null variable when you use it in `Object.keys` so there's no need to additionally use optional chaining on it. Additionally, when you cast `key` into `keyof typeof variable`, you're asserting that it already exists so you can remove the optional chaining before `?.value` as well.

Comment: OK, so how would you do something like `variable && Object.keys(variable).length>1`? If it were a method on the object, it would be `variable?.keys().length > 1` but it isn't...